# How do I change position elements in a queryset?

Tags: python, django

I got:

```
model_list = Models.objects.filter(date_of_addition__gte=today).order_by('name')
```

How do I change position elements in view, for example put 5th (model_list.id=5) element to the top of the list?

template:

```
{% for m in model_list %}
<li>{{m.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And get:

```
Toyota
Audi
BWM
Chevrolet
Honda
VW
```

instead:

```
Audi
BWM
Chevrolet
Honda
Toyota
VW
```

Comment: Isn't work. This is not a simple list, this is object.

Comment: slicing works just fine on querysets.

Comment: You're just sorting by name.  The code sorts by name.  Your "And get:" can't be the output of the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

For your example:

```
for m in [model_list[4]] + model_list[0:4] + model_list[5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `del` to remove an item. Use `insert` to place an item wherever you wish:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> item5 = lst[5]
>>> del(lst[5])
>>> lst
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g']
>>> lst.insert(0, item5)
>>> lst
['f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g']
```

Alternatively, you can just build a new list:

```
newlst = [lst[5]] + lst[:5] + lst[6:]
```

Comment: Querysets are not lists, so this won't work. It will work if you convert it to a list first, though.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: List slicing works just fine for me on querysets.

Comment: @Marcin but it doesn't do what you think it does - it fires off a separate query to the database. Plus, you can't use `del` or `insert` on a queryset.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Well, in that case, I don't see the problem with converting to a list first.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're trying to do

```
model_list = Models.objects.filter(date_of_addition__gte=today,id__gte=5).order_by('name')
```

Or perhaps this

```
model_list = list(Models.objects.filter(date_of_addition__gte=today).order_by('name'))
model_list = [ m for m in model_list if m.id >= 5 ]
```

Hard to say -- based on the question -- what you're trying to do.